# INSERT SELECT MAX connected with text

Tags: mysql, select, insert, max

I want to insert to type field max id from other table but I need to connect it with text information as "Created new user with id =  "MAX(my_employee.id). Code that work but insert only id:

```
INSERT INTO my_logs (user_id, type, date) 
        SELECT '1', MAX(my_employee.id), '2013-05-28 23:52:07' FROM my_employee
```

I tried:

```
INSERT INTO my_logs (user_id, type, date) 
          SELECT '1',"Created new user with id =" MAX(my_employee.id), 
                              '2013-05-28 23:52:07' FROM my_employee
```

and similar but nothing seems to work

Comment: Your query does not look good at all.... consider reprogramming all of the code you just showed....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Are you trying to do this?

```
INSERT INTO my_logs (user_id, type, date) 
      SELECT '1', concat('Created new user with id =', MAX(my_employee.id)), 
             '2013-05-28 23:52:07'
      FROM my_employee;
```

Answer (score 1):

This should work for you:

```
insert into my_logs  
select 1, concat('Created new user with id = ', MAX(id)), '2013-05-28 23:52:07' 
from my_employee
```

- [SQL Fiddle Demo](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/1f1bca/1)